# Informal English structure

Tags: grammar

**"I finish with my homework"**
When i text messages, Usually i get sentence like that

Does the sentence makes any sense and what's formal way to write the sentence?

Comment: It does make sense, but not in the context of your text message. You need the present perfect to describe your action: "I have [just] finished with my homework." You may also describe yourself: "I am finished with my homework."

Comment: Thank you, but I'm just wonder if it's correct or incorrect? Can i use sentence informally when listener knows I'm not native English speaker?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your concern. Of course you can use the sentence, no matter what the listener knows about you. Also, it's very likely any fluent English speaker will understand what you mean. But it's not correct standard English.

Comment: In *informal* conversation or a text message, *I’ve finished my homework.* is the best option here. The more complex phrasal verb “finished with” is unnecessary and unidiomatic in the apparent context and “I have” is almost always contracted to “I’ve” in informal texting or verbal conversation.

Comment: The formal way to write the sentence might be either, *I have finished with my homework.* OR *I have finished my homework.* I still find “finished with” unidiomatic for homework.